# Language parsing - how to deal with multiple options in a rule

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, text-parsing

I have been writing a language parser. It is based on BNF style rules, where a rule contains a list of options, or terminal tokens. E.g.:

```
# Rule A matches the current token stream position if it matches rule B
# followed by rule C followed by a semicolon
rule_a:
  rule_b rule_c ";"

# Rule B matches the current token stream position if the token 
# there equals "foo"
rule_b:
  "foo"

# Rule C matches the current token stream position if it matches
# either rule D or rule E
rule_c:
  rule_d | rule_e

rule_d:
  "bar"

rule_e:
  "bar bar"
```

The specific problem I am running into is what if, when parsing rule C, BOTH rule D and E match the current token stream, but only later on (progressing in rule A) does it become apparent that only one of D or E was the correct choice? When recursing into this kind of syntax tree, it seems like history must be preserved in some way so that a particular syntax tree traversal can be "tried again", but taking a different options than last time.

As an example using the above rules, what if I am trying to parse the following text:

```
foo bar bar;
```

The traversal call tree looks like this, here using indents to show recursion depth.

```
parse(token = "foo", rule = rule_a)
  parse(token = "foo", rule = rule_b)
    parse(token = "foo", rule = terminal_token("foo")
      success: consume "foo", return true
    success: return true
  // So far so good, keep going with rule_a
  parse(token = "bar", rule = rule_c)
    parse(token = "bar", rule = rule_d) // Try rule D first.
      parse(token = "bar", rule = terminal_token("bar")
        success: consume "bar", return true
      success: return true
    success: return true // Rule D matched.
  // Still good, keep going.      
  parse(token = "bar", rule = terminal token ";") // second "bar" here
    fail: return false // "bar" != ";"
  fail: return false. // Sequence rule_b rule_c ";" did not match
```

So now parsing failed, even though it would have succeeded had rule E been tried instead of rule D. I am having trouble coming up with a good way to track what rules have been tried on what token. If rule A ultimately fails as shown above, it really should be tried again, this time trying other options in some of the sub rules - in this case picking the second option (rule_e) when parsing rule_c. But this gets complicated really quickly - with more complex grammars there could be long chains of rules, each with multiple options. So it's not clear to me how you would know from a failed parsing result if there were other ways that parsing could have been tried, and then how to exhaustively try them all.

Comment: This is called in LALR(1) a Shift/Reduce conflict. Since you can both "reduce" rule_d or "shift" rule_e. It's then commonly resolved by setting a priority for the rules in the grammar to decide which one is chosen. If your grammar isn't deterministic, then as @rici pointed out, Earley might be a good choice. There's a reason these algorithms exist, and reinventing the wheel is hard and usually pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Only a very small subset of grammars can be parsed with a predictive parser. Sometimes you can reshuffle your grammar in such a way that it becomes parseable, but there's usually a cost: the grammar becomes harder to read and/or fails to accurately represent the syntactic structure of the language. As you say, backtracking is possible but it requires a certain amount of bookkeeping and can slow down the parse quite a bit.

So it's usually better to leave the grammar as it is and choose a different parsing algorithm, one which can explore more than one possibility at the same time.

If you're lucky, your grammar might turn out to be LALR(1), which is a much larger set of languages than the set which can be parsed with a predictive parser without backtracking. Many programming languages have reasonably simple LALR(1) grammars, or are at least close enough that you can get away with using one and then rejecting the occasional erroneous input while inspecting the parse tree.

For other languages, you can use one of the generalised parsing techniques that explores all possible parses in parallel, maintaining a more complicated parse stack to efficiently represent the various potential parses. One such algorithm was proposed in 1968 by [Jay Earley]; modern variations include GLR and GLL parsers.

There are lots of parser generators which can produce efficient parsers for a variety of such approaches. So there is no need to write it all out by hand, but if you want to give it a go, the Earley algorithm is reasonably simple.